# Do you know how to delete github OAuth token API?

Tags: github, github-api

I'm trying to delete the access token after github login authentication, but it doesn't disappear. Does anyone know any solution??

The error text is as follows.
Error: Request failed with status code 403
data: 'Cookies must be enabled to use GitHub.'

```js
module.exports = async (req, res) => {
  const accessToken = req.body.accessToken;
  try {
    const response = await axios.delete(
      `https://github.com/applications/${CLIENT_ID}/token`,
      {
        data: {
          // client_id: CLIENT_ID,
          access_token: accessToken,
        },
      }
    );
    res.status(205).send('히히 성공했다 카이');
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('에러');
    console.log(e);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to add an auth object (with your client_id and secret as username & passsword) to the axios options:

Ex:

```js
  let ghRes
  try {
    ghRes = await axios.delete(url,
    {         
      auth: { 
       username: clientID, 
       password: clientSecret 
      }, 
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/vnd.github+json', 
        Authorization: 'token ' + accessToken
      },  
      data = { 
        access_token : accessToken 
      }  
    })  
  } catch (err) { log(err) }
```

(also encountered this trip-up and had to dig for a while)